# xskak: defaultmovenr=0 does not work at xskakloop

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I set `\xskakset{defaultmovenr=0,}`. 
And `\mainline{0. Ba8 ... 1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}` will work now. 
But if I use an xskskloop, it does not work any more. 
What do I have to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}
\xskakset{defaultmovenr=0,}% <----- !


\begin{document}
\section{Mainline works}
\newchessgame[setwhite={Ba8}]
\mainline{0. Ba8 ... 1. Be4 ... 2. Bh7 ... 3. Bg8 ... 4. Ba2 ...}
\setchessboard{pgfstyle=straightmove, color=red,}

\section{Loop works not}
%\xskakloop[step=2,]{%
%\begin{tabular}{c}
%\chessboard[tinyboard,  setfen=\xskakget{nextfen},
%] \\[1em]
%movenr: \xskakget{movenr}, lastmovenr: \xskakgetgame{lastmovenr} \\ 
%\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
%\end{tabular}\quad
%}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: numbering of chess moves start by 1 (or something higher if you show a partial game). It can be that in some places zero works, but that is then only by luck.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to hack the command. 
`\renewcommand\xskak@val@defaultmovenr{0}`
But that didn't work here. I don't know what else I have to hack. It would be nice if there was a solution.

Comment: All involved packages (starting with skak from Torben Hoffman which provides the internal chess parser) assume that you use a standard move numbering. And that means that you start with 1. If you want a zero based parsing write your own chess packages. If you hack around you quite probably will break the code in various places.

Comment: Then I hack it differently. I need the text "0. xxx" in the list. More important would be my loop markmove problem. I've created this now after the instructions, but I can't get any further.